# how do I use r data.table env option?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use data.table's recommended method of programming on data.table:
https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/doc/datatable-programming.html#get
But I just get an error.

I'm using R version 4.2.3 and data.table version 1.14.8

```
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.14.8’
> DT = as.data.table(iris)
> v1 = "Petal.Width"
> v2 = "Sepal.Width"
> DT[, .(total = sum(v1, v2)),
+    env = list(v1 = v1, v2 = v2)]
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , .(total = sum(v1, v2)), env = list(v1 = v1,  : 
  unused argument (env = list(v1 = v1, v2 = v2))
```

Comment: try the development version (`data.table::update_dev_pkg()`), otherwise not yet available

Comment: If you look at the top of the page you linked to, you can see those docs are for version 1.14.9 which is the version currently available on github. The version you installed from CRAN does not have that feature.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's confusion about a dev-feature that is not released in production.

Comment: Yes, the docs are for version 1.14.9, but I got confused because the text says "Starting from version 1.14.2, data.table provides a robust mechanism for parameterizing expressions...", so I thought it should be available in version 1.14.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `env` is not an argument in data.table yet

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screen shots, post text samples which StackOverflow renders nicely.